# load common thank you template with different content for different pages

Tags: pages, forms, child-pages

i have created a template called `thank-you.php` and inside that i want to show different content as per the parent url. for e.g. `mywebsite.com/page/thank-you` and `mywebsite.com/another-page/thank-you`. here, i need to load same template but with different content as per the parent url.
`Note:` I need to show this as end result of `hubspot` form submission on different pages.

1. do i need to create a page in admin area for that?
2. do i need to set this page as a child? if so, how can i set as a child for specific pages(around 25 pages)?
3. how can i solve this problem?

I am new to wordpress. any help is appreciated.

Comment: what's the context behind this? Is this the end result of a form submission? Landing pages? Context will help people answer the question as well as understand it

Comment: @TomJNowell yes. it is the end result of form submission. thank you for suggestion. i have edited my question.

Comment: if that's the case, does it really have to be on a different URL? Are you implementing these forms or are you using a plugin? Can you not have the form submit to itself and then display the thankyou instead of the form?

Comment: @TomJNowell 1) it has to be on different url. 2) we are implementing these forms using `hubspot`. 3) i need to show different video on different thank-you page. let's say if i submit the form on `mywebsite.com/page`, i need to show video related to `/page` on `mywebsite.com/page/thank-you` and the same procedure for `mywebsite.com/another-page/thank-you` which shows video related to `/another-page`.

Comment: There's a very high chance that the optimal solution for you is to just create 25 sub-pages with different content in each, especially as they are all different

Comment: @TomJNowell content will remain same, just the video on the page will change.

Comment: the video is still content, there are other ways to do this but they're much more over-complicated and difficult, and will take much more time. Just create 25 pages instead, it will be easier/quicker and you can use a plugin to duplicate the first page to save time.

Answer (score 1):

Create 25 child pages in the admin area and set them to use your template, then update the content for each page to match its parent page

Comment: thank you for your time :)